# Add a reputation and achievements pane to iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, ios-app, achievements-dialog

It'd be nice to see reputation updates in the app, as we get on both the desktop and mobile sites.

**Mock-up of how this would look:**

> [image: mock up for how this would look]

**Other possible icon states:**

> [image: inbox only][image: reputation only][image: badge]

While I understand reputation is shown in the feed, it's a bit unwieldy, and has no notification.

With this feature implemented, the feed could arguably lose both reputation and inbox items, and be left with the interesting questions that fill it up. This would make for a much more consistent UX across app and desktop.

Comment: The main feed view does contain reputation changes, but admittedly there's no real way to isolate them and be immediately aware that there's something new.

Comment: +1 for getting the same "hot network questions" list as on the desktop

Comment: Now that you've marked this status-completed @Arie should the `+10` reputation increase overlay be a separate feature request?

Comment: @mhlester yes, for the one over the achievements button, I assume. We can't can't easily implement that at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beta version of the app now has an achievements button that can be used to access our shiny new achievements screen:

[image: Screenshot of the achievements button]

Comment: This is a fantastic addition. Thank you! The biggest feature I'd still love to see is a small badge count so I can see changes without needing to open the view. Is that planned as part of this feature?

Comment: Also I do visually prefer the way the inbox looks over this, but would of course rather have this implementation than nothing! It really is great.

Comment: Sorry @mhlester, no badge counts for achievements for now. Those are done through push for inbox.

Comment: Yup, I understood you. My answer still holds.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll cross my fingers, but won't hold my breath.

Answer (score 3):

Some kind of reputation activity is something we're planning on for post 1.0 (which is coming soon!).  As soon as we get through the release, we'll be prioritizing a pretty heft list of stuff we want to do.  When we have a concrete direction for this, I (or someone) will come back and tag it [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).

Comment: Hey Ben I just noticed your missing diamond and that you've left SE. Just wanted to say thanks for all you did getting the app where it is. You spent a lot of one on one time helping get to the bottom of issues, and really made our feedback feel valued.

Comment: @mhlester that's very kind of you, thanks :-)

Comment: Excellent  I was going to request this   :-)