# Vote counts in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, vote-count

From the nosy neighbor department: [View number of 'Up' and 'Down' Votes of a question/answer - Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196839/view-number-of-up-and-down-votes-of-a-question-answer-android-app)

I want what they have!

[image: Screenshot of the feature in Android]

Can we see vote counts in the iOS app too?

Comment: Just to confirm that the Android version does have this feature, so +1 for feature-equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coming soon to an iOS device near you:

> [image: Better Than Android™]

To use the feature, press on the question score and hold your finger there until the vote count appears.

Comment: Balance is restored!

Comment: Is there a reason the negative score has no `-`?

Comment: Honestly, because all the questions I had looked at had + with no minus.  This question is `+2/0` for example.  I'll look at the actual logic since browsing more I can't seem to predict how it's going to +/-.

Comment: I think the - just gets cut off if it's a really big number. Here's an example that shows both: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220429/rep-change-achievements-display

Comment: Yup.  I'll be mirroring what you see on the site.  Between 1 and 99 votes, you get a +/-.  Otherwise not.

Comment: Could we also get this for the iPad version?

Comment: [cough cough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251823/revision-history-is-out-of-order-in-the-ios-app) :)

Comment: @BrianNickel I can't seem to do this... :P how long should I press on the score number?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 it looks like it's competing with the swipe to navigate gesture. Holding for a second then swiping down slightly works. I'll look at it on Monday.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 It was exactly what I suspected.  Well be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

Having now seen the Android implementation (HT Andrew T for the edit!) I hate to say it but going modal for that pains me. I much prefer the desktop method.

I decided to mock up a more consistent implementation. It's a lot like the desktop approach, but drops the up/down arrows to save space.

[image: Long press vote area]

[image: See inline vote counts!]

#### Tap again to restore the voting arrows.

---

If the devs also like this implementation, they should feel free to apply it to Android and the mobile site as well! (Not that I could stop them if I wanted to)