# Revision history is out of order in the iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list

When I look at the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/227395/revisions) for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227395/202205) in the iOS app (version 1.2.2), I see the following - notice the revisions are not shown in the correct order:

[image]

Comment: Guess the app doesn't yet handle cases of edits occurring in the exact same time, result of "Approve and Edit" of a suggested edit. Poor Brian will have to find a way to detect such cases and handle. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's a [paging API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=227395&filter=default&site=meta&run=true).  Gonna have to bump that sorting to the server.

Comment: @Brian so it means a fix is upcoming? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard soon. I think I see the cause.

Comment: @BrianNickel awesome! Found another bug/issue with revisions so don't plan any vacation just yet. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next API build. (No app update required.)

The list of versions comes into the API as `1, 2, 3` and has to be reversed to get `3, 2, 1`.  Since the API can return revisions for multiple posts, these get shuffled together using a reverse sort.  Unfortunately the reverse sort algorithm is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) and preserves the order of items with the same timestamp giving us `2, 3, 1`.

The solution was to reverse the entries before applying the sort so 3 and 2 are in the correct order before sorting (and really no sorting has to be done for one post in this case).