# App feed only shows upvotes from SO, not other SE sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

The combined feed on the Android app used to display upvote events from all my accounts. In the last few days, though, I noticed I only see upvotes fron SO itself (which is the only site of the Trilogy I use, so it might be Trilogy-wide). Upvote notifications from other sites (SciFi, RPG, English) don't show up.

Is it a bug on the site? A bug with the web services? A setting I accidentally turned off?

Comment: I've always found the feed reputation a little hit-or-miss. The new Achievements view in the ios app beta is a 1 to 1 match with the topbar though

Comment: That would be best. Hope they port it to the Android app as well.

Comment: My own feed only displays some rep events from 'earlier this week' - the latest one being around June 5th. I've had several rep events since, and they aren't in my feed _at all._ None of these are from Stack Overflow, so I'm seeing nothing. I was wondering what was with that.

Comment: Oh hey, I just got a rep event for an upvote here on meta.se. Still no signs of rep events for any other sites.

Comment: If there's not a feature request for an achievements view on android yet, feel free to make one! The ios request was [pretty popular](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220429/add-a-reputation-and-achievements-pane-to-ios-app)

Comment: Achievements are coming really, really, soon onto Android. Spoilers: http://i.imgur.com/Mv8dSDj.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusingly, the reputation change events that show up in your feed aren't exactly 1 to 1 with the items in your achievements inbox on the site. The feed does consider showing every one of them, but it weighs them against some random factors and whether or not there's other content to show you.

Very soon, we'll have an achievements page on the Android app which will show every single reputation change event you have all in one place, so you don't have to go through the feed and try to find them all.

Comment: Good to know, and thanks for the update.
I do wonder what makes it decide that one upvote in SO is worthwhile, while hitting the repcap on Scifi went unnoticed. :)

Comment: Will reputation then be removed from the feed, or will it continue to show in both places?

Comment: @mhlester the items the feed algorithm considers important enough to show you will still be in your feed

Comment: Ok fair enough. Maybe the threshold for "important" will go up, considering the duplication. But that does make sense